# Keeping data in OpenCL

Tags: c#, opencl

I need to process some data for a long time in OpenCL, and due to time limitation (the driver automatically restarts) I start the kernel many times with different parameters. Each time it has to process the same data, which is about 50 Mb, so I want to copy it only once. I've read many articles and tutorials about OpenCL, but have no idea about how to do this, to keep the data between execution.

If it's important, I use C# binding for OpenCL called OpenCLTemplate.

Comment: Is the ~50MB  always read-only?  It also looks like your are running on a Windows O/S which will reset the OpenCL driver every few minutes  your will lose any data on the GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any data that you store in a global memory buffer will persist on the GPU. You don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just keep a read only buffer for all of your kernel executions and put your results in a different buffer?

What makes you think you have to write to the same buffer you are reading from?

Comment: Now I start the kernel function with all data as an argument, and results as another argument, to which the function writes the resulting data. I don't know how to perstist the data between execution of my kernel, can buffers help me in this case? What would you advice to read about it, especially with examples?

Comment: You are asking, "What is openCL?"  Buffer creation and management is easily more than 50% of the battle with OpenCL.  Understanding the fundamental data structure to communicate between the host and the device is a prerequisite for using the technology.

PyOpenCL is what I used to learn OpenCL. http://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl/

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems;

1) How to  get 50MB of data on to the GPU
2) On windows, the GPU driver will reset frequently when you run long computations
3) A persistence mechanism for ~50MB

Possible answers
1a)  create an OpenCL memory buffer of 50M
1b)  Enqueue  (write) the  data to the GPU
1c)  Set a kernel arg to this buffer
1d)  Access the data as a kernel arg in the GPU's global memory

2)   When the OpenCL driver( graphics) driver resets your application will die.
     You can write script that kills it  before the system does and then restarts the application. The script should read back an intermediate result before it kills the app.
     Otherwise you're never going to be in control.  Only running with a Nvida Tesla GPU
     on Windows or running on Linux will avoids the O/S thinking  display is not functioning  and doing the reset of the driver.

3) I would use MMAPed files to persist the 50MB of data and any intermediate results.  The
  MMAPed file  address can be used to create the OpenCL buffers for the application.

Finally, I will question the approach. Running on Windows vs Linux, due driver reset issues and more. I couldn't find an effective solution to solving driver timeout on Windows even using PostgreSQL database and  my own PgOpenCL, which guarantees all GPU kernel executions are  ACID.

Comment: It's not a problem for my purpose that the kernel can run simultaneously only for about 0.5 seconds (for example, I haven't measured the exact time limit). I need a way to persist data (which is read-only) between executions of the kernel. Now I've understood that a `global buffer` is needed, and started trying to create and use it with C# or python binding ('cause I really don't like C and writing the whole program in this language).

Answer (score -1):

As I have understood from reading online, only one kernel may run simultaneous. This means you should be able to start it with one set of parameters, when complete a new set of parameters can be started and then while that run you can read out the 50mb.

If the driver restarts - this might be due to an error/exception?

Comment: Driver restarts due to time limit: if kernel runs for a long time, Windows shuts it down.

Comment: Simultaneous kernels are unrelated to this; you can actually have different kernels running simultaneously on some GPUs; the data transfers that you suggest are the opposite of what the question is about.